# XSLT greater than / less than working backwords...?

Tags: xml, xslt

This is kinda driving me crazy...  I have an xslt that is passing a value based on choose/when...  It works, but the problem is it's working backwards.  Unless I'm thinking of the equation the wrong way... Here is a section from the XML...

```
<LayoutIntent Class="Intent" Status="Available" ID="id00010">
         <FinishedDimensions DataType="ShapeSpan" Preferred="867.330708661417 498.897637795276 0.0"/>
</LayoutIntent>
```

and here is the xslt section...

```
<xsl:variable name="width">
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(number(substring(ResourcePool/LayoutIntent/FinishedDimensions/@Preferred,1,16))div 72,'#.##')"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="height">
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(number(substring(ResourcePool/LayoutIntent/FinishedDimensions/@Preferred,18,16))div 72,'#.##')"/>
</xsl:variable>
<finishedWidth>
    <xsl:value-of select="$width"/>
</finishedWidth>
<finishedHeight>
    <xsl:value-of select="$height"/>
</finishedHeight>
<xsl:variable name="code">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$width &gt; $height">1</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$width &lt; $height">0</xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
<orientation>
    <xsl:value-of select="$code"/>
</orientation>
```

If the width is greater than the height I would expect 1, but I get 0 and vice versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare numbers, not formatted strings. You have two issues causing it to compare greater than or less than of strings.

1. You are using `xsl:value-of` to select a string
2. You are applying `format-number()` to produce a string

Remove the value-of and have the variable select the numeric product of the division, and move the `format-number()` down to where you want to print the formatted number.

And you might consider changing that second `xsl:where` to `xsl:otherwise`. No sense in repeating the logic for the oppposite if it's going to be one or the other.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/">    
        
        <xsl:variable name="width" as="item()" select="number(substring(ResourcePool/LayoutIntent/FinishedDimensions/@Preferred,1,16))div 72"/>
        <xsl:variable name="height" as="item()" select="number(substring(ResourcePool/LayoutIntent/FinishedDimensions/@Preferred,18,16))div 72"/>

    <finishedWidth>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($width,'#.##')"/>
    </finishedWidth>
    <finishedHeight>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($height,'#.##')"/>
    </finishedHeight>
    <xsl:variable name="code">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$width &gt; $height">1</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <orientation>
        <xsl:value-of select="$code"/>
    </orientation>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Note that this is specific to XSLT 2.0 or higher. In XSLT 1.0 (or in XPath 1.0 compatibility mode) the formatted strings would be converted back to numbers for the comparison. Still, it makes no sense to convert the numbers to strings and then back.

Comment: Rather than as="item()", use "as="xs:double" which makes it even clearer that the variables are numbers, not strings.